# Convert Pandas Operation to SQL Query

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

```
table = (df.groupby('name')['activity'].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0))
```

I have a table that I want to create I can create it in python but I would like to create it in sql to get it sth like following:

```
activity tv football cooking chatting
name
chandler 0   0        3       2
monica   1   1        2       0
ross     3   2       1        1
```

I think it should be something like this but I couldnt take it further.

```
SELECT name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN END) AS ,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN END) AS
  FROM dataset
    GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 2):

So, you want *conditional* aggregation :

```
SELECT name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN activity = 'tv' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS tv,
       SUM(CASE WHEN activity = 'football' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS football,
       SUM(CASE WHEN activity = 'cooking' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cooking,
       . . . 
FROM dataset
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: how can i do it without writing all the conditions, say if there are 1000 different activities? @Yogesh Sharma

Comment: @james look into sqlalchemy or you can just generate your statement with a list comprehension and concatenation in python